# Mayan EDMS ,Calling the API remotely using AJAX getting CORS error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mayanedms

I am creating a new webapp that is going to be making calls to the Mayan EDMS API with javascript/ajax

Currently i am getting a CORS error. My mayan installation is running inside a docker container.

I did find in the settings for Django in the admin->settings-> Django there is a ALLOWED_HOSTS
but there is a green checkmark which indicates it is overwritten by a env var. Any Idea what env var that would be. there is nothing obvious in the .env for the docker file

It appears that django-cors-headers is there as well. Just not sure how to config

How are other people dealing with this?

Thanks
randy